# How to do a FULL OUTER JOIN in KDB?

Tags: join, outer-join, kdb

I have 2 tables `x`,`y` in KDB:

```
x:([a:1 1 2 3]; b:3 4 5 6)
q) a | b
   -----
   1 | 3
   1 | 4
   2 | 5
   3 | 6

y:([a:1 2 2 4]; c:7 8 9 10)
q) a |  c
   ------
   1 |  7
   2 |  8
   2 |  9
   4 | 10
```

I want to do the SQL-equivalent of `x FULL OUTER JOIN y ON x.a = y.a`, that is, I want the result:

```
([a:1 1 2 2 3 4]; b:3 4 5 5 6 0N; c:7 7 8 9 0N 10)
q) a |   b   c
   -----------
   1 |   3   7
   1 |   4   7
   2 |   5   8
   2 |   5   9
   3 |   6 0Nj
   4 | 0Nj  10
```

From the [KDB reference](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/joins/), the closest thing I could find is [`uj`](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/joins/#uj-ujf-union-join) but does not give what I want:

```
x uj y
q) a |   b   c
   -----------
   1 |   3   7
   2 |   5   8
   3 |   6 0Nj
   4 | 0Nj  10
```

So how would I do a `FULL OUTER JOIN` in KDB?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

For a SQL statement like:

select from x,y where x.a=y.a

you can use equijoin verb in  KDB (http://code.kx.com/q/ref/joins/#ej-equi-join).

Ex: If we apply it to your example tables

```
        q> ej[`a;x;y]
```

output:

a     b         c

1   3   7

1   4   7

2   5   8

2   5   9

To get full outer join, simply extract out the non common keys from table x and y and append them to equijoin result.

```
             q> r,(0!x,'y) except r:ej[`a;x;y]
```

This gives you the desired output.

Comment: x,'y will fail if x and y are different lengths. I think you meant to cross

Comment: This is nice but @JPC has a point. However,  replacing `,'` by `cross` doesn't always do the same (it returns more entries). Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: This shouldn't be the accepted answer. It over-fits the example provided by OP without performing a proper outer join.

Answer (score 0):

This gives the result that you asked for

```
q)`a xasc 1!distinct (uj). 0!/:lj'[(x;y);(y;x)]
a| b c
-| ----
1| 3 7
1| 4 7
2| 5 8
2| 5 9
3| 6
4|   10
```

All the best,
Glen

Edit: Added sort

Answer (score -1):

Take a step back and think of what you want and what you have.

You want an outer join which is the union (available in q) of a left join (idem) and a right join (equivalent to left join), so let's just do this:

```
q)oj:{
    lxy:0!lj[x;y];                  // Left join (plus remove keys)
    lyx:(cols lxy) xcols 0!lj[y;x]; // Right join (plus remove keys 
                                    // and prepare cols order for union)
    (cols key x) lxy union lyx      // Union (plus retrieve keys)
    };

q)oj[x;y]
a| b c
-| ----
1| 3 7
1| 4 7
2| 5 8
3| 6
2| 5 9
4|   10
```

Of course, you can then make it an opaque one-liner to fit in the q community:

```
q)(cols key x) xkey ((cols lxy) xcols 0!lj[y;x]) union lxy:0!lj[x;y]
a| b c
-| ----
1| 3 7
2| 5 8
2| 5 9
4|   10
1| 4 7
3| 6
```

**Warning:**
Union assumes it is given two sets, and will return a set. That means that if two rows are identical in one of the two inputs, they will be collapsed to one in the output of `oj`. This is something to keep in mind although it doesn't seem to concern you given your example.